# Error while writing multi-valued function in LateX

Tags: latex, document, mathematical-typesetting

I am creating a document in LateX and the following multivalued function has been giving me trouble for a while.

[image]

The Latex code for the above as I gave is

```
$\[delta \tau_{i,j}^{k}$ = $\left\{$
  \begin{array}{l l}
  \frac{1}{L_{k}} & \quad \mbox{if ant k travels on edge \textit{i,j}} \\
  0 & \quad \mbox{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right. \]
```

While compiling it gives me the following error

```
    ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52 $\[
        delta \tau_{i,j}^{k}$ = $\left\{$
?
```

Any help on fixing this error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aschepler is right--it's the [ inside the $.

You may also want to consider the cases environment, which I think is easier for this sort of thing. For you example, you'd have:

```
\[
    \Delta\tau_{i,j}^k=
    \begin{cases}
        1/L_k & \text{if ant $k$ travels along edge $i,j$} \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Cases environment are definitely easier. Thank you.

Comment: How can I assign a number to the equation in cases environment?

Comment: \\[...\\] is triggering display-math, but as an unnumbered equation. Replacing the \\[ and \\] with \begin{equation} and \end{equation} will give you a numbered equation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use both `$ $` and `\[ \]` like that.  `$` is for in-line equations (fit within a paragraph of text), so you should probably use just `\[ \]` around your equation and remove all the `$`s.

Comment: I tried removing all '$'s from the code. But I still get the error "! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ l.52 [tex]\Delta \tau_{i,j}^{k} = $\left\{$ "

Comment: It's likely the actual error is somewhere before the part you posted, then.

Comment: I had forgot to add amsmath package. :)